# YouTube Video Full-Screen Mode in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, iframe, webview, youtube

I have successfully integrated the YouTube iframe API into my Android app, allowing users to watch embedded YouTube videos in the WebView. However, I want to know if there is any way to enable full-screen mode automatically without requiring the user to manually press the full-screen button within the YouTube player controls.

is there any new developments or workarounds that would allow automatic full-screen mode ?